# PHP - File input type undefined from bootstrap html

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure why the file I am uploading isn't recognized at all. The HTML form is on a separate file from the PHP.

I made sure that file_uploads is turned on from my php.ini configuration.

The HTML:

```
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Verification Photo</label>
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="verphoto" name="verphoto" required>
          <small class="form-text text-muted">Only supports JPG. Max size : 5mb</small>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

PHP:

```
                                        //check file type
                                    $target_dir = "../z2tools/userimages/";
                                    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["verphoto"]["name"]);
                                    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                                    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["verphoto"]["tmp_name"]);
                                    if($check !== false) {
                                        //check file size
                                        if ($_FILES["verphoto"]["size"] < 5000000) {
                                            //resize
                                            $file_tmp_name = $_FILES["verphoto"]["tmp_name"];
                                            $ratio = $width/$height;
                                            if($ratio > 1) {
                                              $new_width = 350;
                                              $new_height = 350/$ratio;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                               $new_width = 350*$ratio;
                                               $new_height = 350;
                                            }
                                            // Rename file
                                            $temp = explode('.', $target_file);
                                            $newfilename = $usernick.'.'.end($temp);
                                            // Upload image
                                            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name , $target_dir.$newfilename)) {
                                                $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($target_dir.$newfilename));
                                                $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                                                imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
                                                imagedestroy($src);
                                                imagepng($dst, $target_dir.$newfilename);
                                                imagedestroy($dst);
                                                //upload success
                                                echo '<p><img class="iconsize" src="image/mail.gif"/></p>';
                                                echo '<p>upload success.</p>';
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                //upload failed
                                                echo '<p><img class="iconsize" src="image/errors.png"/></p>';
                                                echo '<p>upload failed.</p>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            //invalid file size
                                            echo '<p><img class="iconsize" src="image/errors.png"/></p>';
                                            echo '<p>Invalid file size.</p>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //invalid file type
                                        echo '<p><img class="iconsize" src="image/errors.png"/></p>';
                                        echo '<p>Invalid file type uploaded.</p>';
                                    }
```

And the result is always `verphoto is undefined`.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the enctype attribute of your form set to multipart/form-data?

Comment: not at all. could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes. That's probably all that's missing.

Comment: From the php docs: Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.

Comment: please place this as the answer. This have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common issue with php file uploads is the missing `enctype` attribute on the `form` tag.

From the php docs: "Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work"

Make sure your form tag looks something like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="..." ...>
```